# How to use mod_rewrite on an Nginx

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I would like to use an Nginx Server instead of an Apache. In my `.htaccess` File i have this lines.

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./nice_urls.php
```

Any ideas how this would work on Nginx?

Comment: It wouldn't. http://winginx.com/htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Nginx does not have out of the box support for .htaccess files.

The easy way is to use the following rule in nginx config file for you vhost:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /nice_urls.php?$args;
```

On Nginx try_files is basically a replacement for the typical mod_rewrite style file/directory existence check. It is supposed to be more efficient than using if - see http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Also you must configure Nginx to return SCRIPT_FILENAME to your application.
If you use fastcgi you must check fastcgi.conf to have this line:
`fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`

If this line doesn't exist, add it in fastcgi.conf or you vhost config file.